# Run time time out exception on couch base client

Tags: java, couchbase

While updating(Upsert) the document we have been getting the time out exception.

couch base server version: 3.0.3 enterprise edition

couch base client - 2.1.2

Configuration:

```
connectTimeout: 10000
viewTimeout: 75000
queryTimeout: 75000
```

Setting:

```
// Create couchbase cluster client
CouchbaseEnvironment couchEnv = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
.connectTimeout(configuration.getCouchbase().getConnectTimeout())    //10000ms = 10s, default is 5s
.viewTimeout(configuration.getCouchbase().getViewTimeout())
.queryTimeout(configuration.getCouchbase().getQueryTimeout())
.autoreleaseAfter(5000)
.build();

cluster =  CouchbaseCluster.create(couchEnv,configuration.getCouchbase().getHosts());
bucket = cluster.openBucket(configuration.getCouchbase().getBucket(), configuration.getCouchbase().getPassword());
```

Code:

```
public UserDocument updateUserDocument(UserDocument userDocument)
throws Exception {
    userDocument.setLastUpdatedTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    JsonObject userDocObject = JsonObject.fromJson(gson
.toJson(userDocument));
    JsonDocument userDocumentJson = JsonDocument.create(
    String.valueOf(userDocument.getUserId()), userDocObject);
    //Getting Timeout Exception here
    JsonDocument responseDoc = bucket.upsert(userDocumentJson);

    // update device mappings in redis
    if (userDocument.getUserDevices() != null &&  userDocument.getUserDevices().size() > 0) {
        for (UserDevice userDevice : userDocument.getUserDevices())
        { 
            redisClientService.putDeviceMappingInCache( userDevice.getDeviceId(), userDocument.getPartnerId(), userDocument); 
        }
    }

    return gson.fromJson(responseDoc.content() != null ? responseDoc.content().toString() : null, UserDocument.class);
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR [2015-07-28 12:16:59,120] com.personagraph.dropwizard.resource.UserManagementResource: Internal Error in gettting user details
! java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
! Causing: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
! at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:93) ~[pgweb-usermanagement-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at com.couchbase.client.java.view.DefaultViewRow.document(DefaultViewRow.java:44) ~[pgweb-usermanagement-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at com.couchbase.client.java.view.DefaultViewRow.document(DefaultViewRow.java:39) ~[pgweb-usermanagement-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

Can anyone please let me know if I need any setting or code changes

Comment: Tip: Since you're already using Gson for marshalling/unmarshalling entities, you can skip the JsonObject altogether by using the string based RawJsonDocument

Comment: Your code shows an upsert but the error is about a view query, is that the correct log?